# Get VirtualizingStackPanel non-realized item index

Tags: c#, wpf, indexing, virtualization

Is it possible to get the index of an item in a WPF VirtualizingStackPanel that hasn't been realized without directly querying the ItemsControl's data source?  The only thing I can think of is to use the ItemContainerGenerator but I haven't found anything that returns an index for an item.

I'm essentially trying to determine if a specific item is listed before or after the current viewport range for a horizontal stack panel.

```c#
// ? get item index

if (itemIndex < 0) return;

var viewIndexLeft = virtualizingStackPanel.HorizontalOffset;
var viewIndexRight = viewIndexLeft + virtualizingStackPanel.ViewportWidth;

if (itemIndex < viewIndexLeft)
{
    // indicate LEFT
}
else if (itemIndex > viewIndexRight)
{
    // indicate RIGHT
}
```

Comment: Return item's index is simple :`  Panel.Children.IndexOf(...)`

Comment: I need find the index of a databound item that does not have a UIElement in the virtualizing stackpanel yet.  My workaround so far is to get the panel's ItemsControl and do a search on its ItemsSource, but surely there's a more efficient way.